# My Axios POST request in a React app is not working

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

Hi I have an application with GET, POST and DEL requests. One of my POST requests works, but two of my POST requests don't work.

this POST request works

```
    onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user  = {
        username: this.state.username
    }

    console.log(user);

    axios.post('https://pure-ocean-29656.herokuapp.com/users/add', user)
        .then (res=> console.log(res.data));
        

    this.setState ({
        username: ''
    })
    
}
```

This POST request doesn't work

```
    onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const exercise  = {
        username: this.state.username,
        description: this.state.description,
        duration: this.state.duration,
        date: this.state.date
    }

    console.log(exercise);

    axios.post('https://pure-ocean-29656.herokuapp.com/exercises/add', exercise)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));


    window.location = '/';
}
```

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong? Here's the repository: https://github.com/adnjoo/merncrud

Live application frontend: https://thawing-crag-17351.herokuapp.com/

Live application backend: https://pure-ocean-29656.herokuapp.com/exercises

When I run the server locally and use http://localhost:5000/exercises/add in place of the heroku link, I am able to successfully do the POST request.

I was also able to do the POST request using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).

Comment: You are likely immediately doing something instead of putting the thing you want to happen after the request in the axios callback. Put things you want to happen after the request in the axios callback.

Comment: "not working" is awfully nonspecific. Are you getting errors? Which ones?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the redirect line
and use in "then"

```
window.location = '/';
```

The request is in the process while your page redirect to slash So that's why the request is not proceeding completely